# XBee, how does it deal with collisions?

Tags: xbee, protocol

I'm getting started with XBEE S2 modules and I have a doubt I still couldn't get a clarification, hope you guys can help.

I want to have 2 end devices transmitting data to one coordinator, all of them working in API mode (escaped characters). The data should be sent "as fast as possible" so I'm afraid I will get many collisions. How XBEE deals with that?

On the the RX packets I can get the source address but I need to read many bytes before I know it. What happens if while I'm reading bytes from a packet the other end device starts to send another packet?
If XBEE implicitly uses collision avoidance, are that "per byte" or "per packet"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The radio being used by these modules (MAC & PHY layer) is defined by the [IEEE 802.15.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) standard which specifies the use of [Carrier sense multiple access with collision avoidance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSMA/CA) or abbreviated as **CSMA/CA**.

A simple summary, a device will do a quick scan of the channel that its PAN network is on and if it senses that it is being utilized it will wait and retry using a random exponential backoff scheme. Using this method, you can think of the channel as a shared resource that is "taken" by a device to do a burst transmission and then released for others to use.

Further questions about reliable transport can be answered by reading about it in the Zigbee spec or IEEE 802.15.4 spec.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! But... is the collision avoidance "per byte" or "per packet". I guess "per byte" doesn't make much sense but I would like to make sure of that.

Comment: @msr Definitely per packet. Also note that collision avoidance isn't 100% successful - you still need to have an acknowledgement channel and retransmissions to make it a reliable transport

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of XBee, but I believe it's a pretty heavyweight protocol. As such I would wager it employs both collision avoidance (at the medium access control level) and automatic retransmissions (akin to TCP) and does so at the packet level.